# Nautilus Crashes when Dragging and Dropping Files - Wiley

Tags: nautilus, crash, drag-and-drop

I'm using the 64-bit version of Wiley.

When dragging and dropping files using Nautilus (or other file mgmt apps) the application crashes.  I've read a couple of other threads on the same topic but they do not seem to apply to my situation, though I've gone to the trouble of re-installing Ubuntu as recommended by a couple of the answers.

I recall one of the threads speculated that the issue is with compiz.  One of the people in the thread had tried dragging and dropping without compiz running and Nautilus didn't crash.

I'm running the latest version of nVidia proprietary drivers with dual monitors.

When I run Nautilus from terminal, here's what the terminal tells me when it happens:

---

```
kerry@kerry-All-Series:~$ nautilus
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.


(nautilus:6283): Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'nautilus' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 4057 error_code 3 request_code 141 (Composite) minor_code 8)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
kerry@kerry-All-Series:~$
```

Comment: Judging by the other reports of this problem I've found and my own experiences with Firefox and Geeqie (but not Chrome or Qt-based apps) under KWin, it appears to be a bug in GTK+ that's made worse by desktop compositing, but isn't exclusive to it. (ie. I turn off KWin's compositing with Alt+Shift+F12 and it becomes less common but doesn't go away entirely.)